# How do you select a iframe if it has a specfic word in its src in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Alright so say you are viewing a website and a iframe appeared and it has a source of example.com/ANWU2bu2nSADF. So it would look like this:

```
<iframe src="example.com/ANWU2bu2nSADF"></iframe>
```

But more than one of these Iframes are on the page, so for example

```
<iframe src="example.com/23OAnlMN1kPAI"></iframe>
<iframe src="example.com/J2Os9MAnmNWO1"></iframe>
```

So I want to create a javascript that can put these select these and then change the source, issue is that I dont know how to select the iframe just by its source including the domain example.com in it, I would like to do it in javascript in it but I am still unable to figure it out. Anyone know how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `window.frames` which holds all the frames on the page. 
[Documentation on window.frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe[src="example.com/ANWU2bu2nSADF"]')
```

for jquery or

```
document.querySelector("iframe[src='example.com/ANWU2bu2nSADF']")
```

for javascript.

Comment: No, I am looking to get every iframe that has the src that has a specifc domain in it, not looking at the stuff after the /

Comment: Then you can add a * to src= like so and just search on the domain.

    $('iframe[src*="example.com"]')

[I suggest you look at some documentation for more selectors if you need them](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)